# How to get the progress of a conecting to wireless connection

Tags: android, wifi

I'm making a app that is displaying the available wireless networks and a user can choose one network and connect to it.

I have a broadcast receiver and I receive the status of the connection :connected , when the connection is done , but I would like also to display more info to the user like ,  Authenticating, Obtaining IP address , cause now I only know when network is connected but noting till then.
Any idea how to do this?

Thanks you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fine-grained connection state is available from the NetworkInfo object - [getDetailedState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#getDetailedState())

```
NetworkInfo ni = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
DetailedState state =  ni.getDetailedState();
```

You also need to register your broadcast receiver to receive state change events from WifiManager

```
IntentFilter filter = 
   new IntentFilter(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION); 
filter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION);
filter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
filter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
```